# Как получить объект из jobject, подходящий под условия?

Tags: c#, json

У меня есть следующий JObject:

```
"Payload": {
   "event_data": {
      "items": {
         {
           "type": "category",
           "id": "territory",
         },
         {
           "value": "$root",
           "type": "operator",
         },
         {
           "value": "",
           "type": "identifier:card"
         },
         {
           "value: "",
           "type": "image:subject"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Задача такая: заменять value у объекта, который имеет "image:subject". Как мне найти такой объект, значение у которого, можно заменить?

Comment: Какая-то json поломанная...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсим строку в JSON, доходим по элементам до `items`, перебираем его и меняем значение по условию

Пример:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;


public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        var jsonStr = @"
{
    'Payload': {
        'event_data': {
            'items': [
                {
                    'type': 'category',
                    'id': 'territory'
                },
                {
                    'value': '$root',
                    'type': 'operator'
                },
                {
                    'value': '',
                    'type': 'identifier:card'
                },
                {
                    'value': '',
                    'type': 'image:subject'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
        ";
        
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonStr);
        
        foreach (var item in json["Payload"]["event_data"]["items"])
        {
            if (item["type"].ToString() == "image:subject")
            {
                item["value"] = "ABC";
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
{
  "Payload": {
    "event_data": {
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "category",
          "id": "territory"
        },
        {
          "value": "$root",
          "type": "operator"
        },
        {
          "value": "",
          "type": "identifier:card"
        },
        {
          "value": "ABC",
          "type": "image:subject"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо! я как обычно.. в погоне за красивым решением, упускаю простой вариант

Comment: @penancewarrior, пожалуйста :)